# VS2013 migrating automátically my db even when AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, database-migration

I have an application with several code based migrations (EF5 code first) and an initializer that inherits from CreateDatabaseIfNotExists then I install that application on a production machine for the first time leting CodeFirst create the database from scratch. After that I add another code based migration and generate the migration script on my development machine and apply that script on the production machine. Then when I run my app on the production machine I'm getting errors. Those errors were generated because the code on my migrations are not being executed and there are code on those migrations that must be executed (for instance I have File Stream on my db).

Then, to solve that I changed my initializer to MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion with AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false. That solution solved the problem of executing all migrations code on first create but now I have this problem: VS2013 migrates the database automaticaly (if I add another migration) what I expect is to have an exception because AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false in VS2012 that is happening BUT VS2013 IS MIGRATING AUTOMATICALLY.

Why is that happening? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Automatic Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ554735.aspx) Enabled refers to the process of trying to automatically migrate your database to match your DbContext.  For example, say you create your DbContext and run it once.  Then you add a new table.  With Automatic Migrations, you don't need to run Add-Migration, you can just run your app again and EF will automagically modify your database (note: it doesn't do this for all schema changes, but it makes a good effort.  Sometimes you will still need to use Add-Migration).

Since your initializer is set to MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion, any time the DbContext initialized it will run all of the migrations that are available.  If there is any mismatch between your DbContext and *the schema your migrations generate*, you'll get an exception.

It sounds like the scenario you're expecting is when there is a mismatch between your DbContext and *your database*, you should get an exception.  If this is what you want, you should not set your initializer to MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that I can't find any initializer that runs all code based migrations on Db creation.

Comment: The second problem is that VS2012 and VS2013 are behaving diffrently: with MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion and AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false I expect an exception when there is a mismatch. So what I really need is something that runs all code-based migrations on first create. Thanks

Comment: @jcgalveza So you want to run all migrations when creating the DB, but don't run migrations if the DB already exists?